# Behaviors are not supported in d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

Trying to upgrade d3 in my project, but error prompted:
`Cannot read property 'drag' of undefined`
It's caused by using `d3.behavior.drag()`

Here is the document of **Behaviors** for V3
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Behaviors

But it's seems it's not supported in v4
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/4

It's that API in already in roadmap, or there is some better way to implement behavior now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer it myself:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2461
It still on the way, will be there in a separate module.

2 April 17, Update: it supported in v4 now